# how connect regex replace to function in c++

Tags: c++, regex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
std::string ty(std::string text){
    if(text == "brown")
        return "true";
    else
        return "qw";
}
int main()
{
   std::string text = "Quick $brown fox";
   std::cout << '\n' << std::regex_replace(text, std::regex(R"(\\$(.*))"), ty("$&")) << '\n';
}
```

i use c++11 . I try without if worked but with if don't work ? i don't know what to do

Comment: Don't add spurious tags. This is as removed from C as one can get.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of different things wrong with the original code.

Firstly here's some working code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

std::string ty(std::string text){
    if(text == "brown")
        return "true";
    else
        return "qw";
}
int main()
{
    std::string text = "Quick $brown fox";
    std::smatch m;
    if (std::regex_search(text, m, std::regex(R"(\$([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*))")))
    {
        std::cout << '\n' << ty(std::string(m[1].first, m[1].second)) << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nno match\n";
    }
}
```

Some things that were wrong with the original code

Firstly the function being called was wrong. Use `std::regex_search` to search for matches in a string. Capture the results in an `std::smatch` object and then use those results to call the `ty` function.

The regex was wrong in two different ways. Firstly `\\` is wrong because you are using a raw string literal, so only a single backslash is required. Secondly `(.*)` is wrong because that will match the entire rest of the string. You only want to match the word following the dollar. I've used `([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)` instead. That might not be exactly what you want but it works for this example. You can modify it if you want.

Comment: I want to replace the answer should be like this "real fast fox"

Comment: @nima_cpp Then that would be `std::cout << '\n' << text.replace(m[1].first, m[1].second, ty(std::string(m[1].first, m[1].second))) << '\n';`

Comment: @nima_cpp Although I'm not sure where `fast` is coming from.

Comment: Thank you it work . yeah sorry i mean `true`

Comment: but string has `$` How can I delete it?

Comment: @nima_cpp The part that is replaced is the part inside the brackets in the regex, so change `R"(\$([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*))"` to `R"((\$[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*))"`